# Show images in jquery image list view

Tags: ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile, jsonp

Why is it that some pictures does not show up in jQuery Mobile image list view in iOS simulator?

Instead of images, it shows a blue box with a question mark. If there was a URL problem, surely all the images would show the icon with question mark, but some images shows up perfectly fine.

I resized the images into smaller sizes but that didn't solve the problem. How can I fix this issue?

This is the javascript that get the images from mysql database. All the images are in backend root folder.

```
.$(function () {
        var serviceUrl = 'http://localhost/Backend/getDinner.php?jsoncallback=?';
        var dataStore = {};
        $.ajax({
                  url: serviceUrl,
                  crossDomain: true,
                  dataType: "jsonp",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  jsonpCallback:'jsoncallback',
                })
            .success(function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item){
            // Stash the items by id for later retrieval.           
            dataStore[item.ID] = item;
            var $row = $(
            '<li>' +
             '<a data-transition="slide" href="#detailsPage">' +
            '<img src="' + item.ImageURL + ' ">' + 
            '<h2>' + item.Title + '</h2>' +
            '<h2>' + 'Price :'+ item.Price + '</h2>' +
            '</a>' +  '</li>');
          $('#output').append($row);
```

Here is the HTML, that gets the list view.

```
<div data-role="content" data-scroll="true" > 
  <ul id="output" data-role="listview" ></ul>
```

Here is the screenshot of the IOS screen.

[image]

Comment: can you post here the value of the Item.ImageURL?

Comment: Do you mean the "ImageURL":"images\/dinner\/breakfast5.jpg",

Answer (score 0):

The only time that I've seen this is when the image name is improperly typed or the location of the file is not correct.

For example:The correct file name: "images/myimage.png" is mistyped as "images/myimge.png" or the url or file location is incorrect.

You may want to recheck that your url location and file name is properly typed without errors.